# XtraGrid checkEdit repository could not be checked/unchecked

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

I've devexpress XtraGrid populated with data using linq/LinqInstantFeedbackSource. The XtraGrid has a checkEdit repository bind with a column named Status from a table. The data elements in Status column are bits (0 or 1). However, for some unknown reason, the checkEdit could not be selected - i.e. I can't check/uncheck it. What could be the possible reason??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the [LinqInstantFeedbackSource](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressDataLinqLinqInstantFeedbackSourcetopic) is a read-only data source.

**UPDATE:**
As far as I can see you are using the anonymous type as result. **Objects of the anonymous type have only read-only properties**.  It's impossible to modify them. That's why there are no editing in XtraGrid. If you need to obtain a collection of editable objects, don't use anonymous types.
You can use this code, for example:

```
var tcs=
    from tc in dc.TC 
    join dpt in dc.Departments on tc.DeptID equals dpt.DeptID 
    where tc.isReturned.Equals(0) 
    select new EditableObject { 
        MRN=tc.MRN, 
        DeptName=dpt.deptName + " - " + dpt.roomNo,
        IsReturned= tc.isReturned
    };
```

where `EditableObject` is:

```
public class EditableObject{
    public string MRN { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }
    public bool IsReturned { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've changed that but it is still not working. I'm just pulling the data using linq and join. Will it have any effect? Besides, the data type of the column is bit

Comment: @user758961 Please provide the exact code of XtraGrid's settings

Comment: var tcs=(from tc in dc.TC join dpt in dc.Departments on tc.DeptID equals dpt.DeptID where tc.isReturned.Equals(0) select new {
tc.MRN,deptName=dpt.deptName + " - " + dpt.roomNo,tc.isReturned});

gridTC.DataSource =tcs;